# How to prove the inequality of solutions for two Cauchy problems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, lipschitz-functions, cauchy-problem

Consider two continuous and Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable functions $g_1:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g_2:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_1\le g_2$. Also, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are functions defined on $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi_i(t,x)=g_i(t,\phi_i(t,x))\\
\phi_i(0,x)=x\;.
\end{equation}
$$ 
How to prove that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are increasing in $x$ and $\phi_1\le\phi_2$? **Thank you for your suggestion.**